# How can use a php file to change values on a different php web page

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a webpage containing two forms. I then have a seperate .php file containing the code of what I want to happen when each is submitted.

The first form is a search form and the action is performed on the following php file.

```
<?php
include newCustomer.php;
connect('final');//connect to DB

$query = $_POST['searchDB']; 
    $query = htmlspecialchars($query);
    $query = mysql_real_escape_string($query); 

     $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM customer WHERE First_Name LIKE '$query'") ;//query the DB with search field in colleumn selected//

     //$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM customer INNER JOIN address ON customer.ID = address.Customer_ID LEFT OUTER JOIN sites ON address.ID = sites.address_ID WHERE upper(customer.$field) LIKE'%$query%'") ;

    if($data === FALSE) {
    $error = 'Query error:'.mysql_error();
    echo $error;
    }
    else
    {

    $test = array();
    $colNames = array();
    while($results = mysql_fetch_assoc($data)){// puts data from database into array, loops until no more

    $test[] = $results;

        }
         $anymatches=mysql_num_rows($data); //checks if the querys returned any results
        if ($anymatches != 0) {
    $colNames = array_keys(reset($test));

    }

            if ($anymatches == 0) 
                    { 
                        echo "Sorry, but we can not find an entry to match your query<br><br>"; 
                    } 

    } 
header("location: newCustomer.php");
echo test;
die();
?>
```

I want to use the data contained in the array on the newCustomer page. but I cant get it to appear, I tried echoing 'test' in random places in the search.php file but it wont appear on the newCustomer page.

How can I pass information between the two?

Comment: Is this the actual code, because that include statement is invalid for one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The php **[`header`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)** function redirects the user to a new page, it does this on the client side (in their browser), not the server side.

So when you do `header("location: newCustomer.php");` this doesn't take place on the server side, only on the client side. This means that no information can be passed from the code above (form action page) into newCustomer.php.

To fix this you need to store the data somewhere on the server, and then retrieve it from newCustomer.php. It's hard to say exactly what you should do in your specific case, because I don't know your code, but for this you can use [**sessions**](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php), [**cookies**](http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php), database etc.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you `newCustomer.php` is in the same forlder as your `search.php`, so you are missing quotes `''` just surround it, change to

```
include 'newCustomer.php';
```

Comment: also missing quotes around the echo.

should be `echo 'test';` or `echo print_r($test);` if you want to print out the variable.

Answer (score 0):

you can set the array to a session variable that you can then  gain access to when the next page has loaded up.

eg $_SESSION['myarray'] = $myarray

then when the next page loads load up the session session_start(); then you can get at the array via $_SESSION['myarray']

Alternatively uou could convert the array to a string (seperate the items with a special character like ,)  and pass it through the header of the page then on the next page take that string and use a function called explode() that will take that string and turn it into an array.